# Remove comma and next 3 characters from line with sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed, csv

I'm writing a shell script to send fail2ban logs to a postgres database.
The event timestamps in the application log annoyingly shows the milliseconds of the event separated with a comma (like this: 11:01:26,899), which postgres doesn't like and I don't need, here's an example of a line from the log:

```
2023-02-09 11:01:26,899 fail2ban.filter         [6823]: INFO    [sshd] Found xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - 2023-02-09 11:01:26
```

This is the only place in the file where a comma is present.
Is it possible to use sed to remove this comma and the next 3 characters?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. (1) The answer to "is it possible?" is "yes". I guess the real question is "how can we do it?". If it is, then it's better to *explicitly* ask this. (2) Any question should show reasonable research effort. What have you tried with `sed`? How did your tries fail? ([edit] the question). (3) Hint: "remove a string" = "replace the string with an empty string".

Comment: perhaps another useful hint to @KamilMaciorowski's response is to suggest you also check out "regular expressions". The good news is that the solution should be pretty straightforward given these two hints. Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

The following command removes substrings consisting of a comma and three characters following the comma:

```
sed 's/,...//' input.log
```

Notes and explanations:

- Technically the `s` command does a replacement. We remove something by replacing it with an empty string. In our code the relevant empty string is between the second and the third slash.
- In regex `,` is literal, `.` matches any character.
- I put the expression inside single-quotes. In this case such quoting is unnecessary, but in general `sed` code often contains characters that would be interpreted by the shell (and we don't want this), therefore it's good to get used to quoting.
- Our command does at most one replacement per line of input. In a line, only the first matching substring will be replaced.
- `,...` is a simple pattern. If each line starts with a timestamp in the given format then [there is no need for a complex pattern or logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

Answer (score 0):

Given the file `input.log`, the following `sed` command would remove the milliseconds component from the timestamp:

```
sed -r 's/([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})(,[0-9]{3})/\1/' input.log
```

This substitutes the above two capture groups (capture group one being the time in `%H:%M:%S` and capture group two being the comma and milliseconds `,%3N`) with the first capture group.

This could then be redirected to another file:

```
sed -r 's/([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})(,[0-9]{3})/\1/' input.log > output.log
```

Where `output.log` is the output file.

**Update:** Removed unnecessary `g` flag. See @kamil-maciorowski's answer for a simpler and more succinct solution.